# Netbeans is not deleting custom created files/folders when uninstalled?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have created a netbeans module which creates a folder within the netbeans installed directory location.This module is used for logging syslog messages.The log messages are stored in separate files in this folder.I have observed that when i uninstall netbeans altogether from my system this folder is not deleted.How can i make netbeans delete these folders and files when it uninstalls itself(or when the module is uninstalled).

Comment: So when you uninstall it will ask whether to delete the folders and associated projects

Comment: Actually it will ask but these folders and files are not included in that list.How do i register these files to that list?